# evaluate formulas with access database engine

Tags: c#, excel, ms-access, openxml, ms-jet-ace

I am trying to plug in some info to a spreadsheet and grab some values calculated via formula. This is all done via c#.

Can the ACE driver evaluate formula's or should I go with interop or some other solution?

I tried with open xml sdk too and that doesn't seem to evaluate formulas either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SpreadsheetGear for .NET can evaluate Excel compatible formulas using C# in any .NET 2.0+ application. You can see live C# Excel compatible calculation samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/calcengine.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC